# fork function in c programing

Tags: c, fork

I have this bit of code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void createChild(){
 int pid;
pid=fork();
if(pid<0){
 printf("creation error");exit()
}
if(pid>0)return;
printf("Processus of number %d\n",getpid());
}

int main()
{
  createChild();
  createChild();
  createChild();
}
```

I need to know how many process this code generate and a proper explanation  ? please any help

Comment: this code will generate 3 subprocess

Comment: can u please explain for me why ?

Comment: see my answer for the explaination

Comment: I would expect 15 childs, if I haven't miscalculated.

Comment: can u explain why please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happens:

```
Process: Actions

1: [fork (creates 2)] [fork (creates 3)] [fork (creates 5)] [end of main]
2:                    [fork (creates 4)] [fork (creates 6)] [end of main]
3:                                       [fork (creates 7)] [end of main]
4:                                       [fork (creates 8)] [end of main]
5:                                                          [end of main]
6:                                                          [end of main]
7:                                                          [end of main]
8:                                                          [end of main]
```

You can see a clear exponential of base two here. Each [`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) creates a child that starts execution from the return of the fork call. (you can differ the child from the parent with the return value.)